# AppsScript Regex for TextValidation on form questions isn't recognizing numbers OR characters

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am having trouble with my regex for TextValidation on form questions

I want to validate that users are inputting a number or "N/A."

To do this, I tried the regex pattern `(\\d*)|(N/A).` But there seems to be an error because it isn't validating anything.

I tried a few other things:

Using `(\\d*)` works to validate answers are numbers.

Using `(N/A)` works to validate answers are "N/A."

Using `(N/A)|(n/a)` works to validate answers are "N/A" or "n/a."

I'm beyond confused why `(\\d*)|(N/A)` isn't working. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the code I am using:

```
let item = form.addTextItem();
let textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
   .setHelpText('Take another look matey')
   .requireTextMatchesPattern("(\\d*)|(N/A)")
   .build();
item.setValidation(textValidation);
```

Comment: Try: ^\d+$|^N\/A$ My understanding is that this will match an entry consisting of 1) any numbers OR 2) a specific string = N/A but nothing more. My limited testing confirms.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
let item = form.addTextItem();
let textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
   .setHelpText('Take another look matey')
   .requireTextMatchesPattern("^(\\d*|N\\/A)$") // or .requireTextMatchesPattern("^(\\d*|N\\/A|n\\/a)$")
   .build();
item.setValidation(textValidation);
```

- In this case, `^(\\d*|N\\/A)$` is used instead of `(\\d*)|(N/A)`.
- By this modification, numbers and a string of "N/A" can be used.